# Why can $v_x,v_y$ in ${\bf{v}}=(z,z,z)$ contain the $z$ variable?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

I am rather confused why the vector field:

$${\bf{v}}=(z,z,z)$$

can contain the $z$ variable in the $x$ and $y$ components any help with explaining this would be great.

Comment: This is just saying whatever value you choose for $z$ also defines the $x$ and $y$ coordinate. This is no different than if you were to look at the line $y = x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector field assigns to every point in space a vector.    This one takes a point in space and assigns the vector that is the z coordinate in all 3 directions. I would find it more natural for it to use angle brackets to indicate that the output is a vector and not a point,  so

$$v(x,y,z)=\langle z,z,z \rangle$$

For example,  this would assign the vector $\langle 3,3,3 \rangle$
to every point on the plane $z=3$

Comment: Nitpick remark: If you want to use angle brackets, then use the actual angle brackets `\langle` and `\rangle`, not the less-than and greater-than signs `<` and `>`.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't think I've ever used that style in my own handwriting when doing this, but sure, updated.

Comment: The thing is that the spacing becomes terribly ugly with `<` and `>`, since they are interpreted as relational symbols rather than delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

The velocities $v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ are velocities that point in the $x$ and $y$ directions. They can also depend on depth, $z$. Think of velocities in a stream that are zero at the bottom of the river, and peak at the surface of the river. These components increase as the coordinate system elevation above the river bottom increases from 0 to $z=H$.

Alternatively, think of a head wind to a horizontally flying aeroplane. That velocity depends on elevation above ground, but points (let's say) due North.